# slf4j with log4j, no configuration files but I can see logs in file

Tags: logging, log4j, slf4j

working on a project using slf4j with log4j(coa I can see all needed log4j jar files in place. Not using loopback or java logging util.)
But I could not find any configuration files (such as xml file) anywhere.
But I can see all logs go to a file with DEBUG level on.
My question is, is this the default behavior of log4j? Or it must exist a config file somewhere?
If I add config file, where is the right place to do so?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default configuration is to log only errors to the console.(log4j2)

the rootlogger is defaulted to debug but is only the console only with the basic configurator (log4j1)

From official doc

> This occurs when the default configuration files log4j.properties and log4j.xml can not be found and the application performs no explicit configuration. log4j uses Thread.getContextClassLoader().getResource() to locate the default configuration files and does not directly check the file system. Knowing the appropriate location to place log4j.properties or log4j.xml requires understanding the search strategy of the class loader in use. log4j does not provide a default configuration since output to the console or to the file system may be prohibited in some environments.

If you can't see a configuration file (log4j.xml most probably), it could be configured in code with the DOMConfigurator class or the config file could be specified as a command line argument (-Dlog4j.configurationFile i think, might be different for log4j 1.x).

Usually you place the configuration file in the root of your classpath directory for example main class is src/com/Main.class, the config file would be in the src/ folder.

I would search for the import statement import org.apache.log4j, if youre using slf4j there should not be any references to this package except for custom config/logging